# Plotting animate 3d graph from file.txt

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 3D animate Graph taking the data from file.txt. I got a    issue with the animation function, such as when I'm introducing new coordinate on txt file the plot doesn't update by itself. The code is the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
def animate(i):
   point_stress=open(r'Prova.txt','r').read()
   lines=point_stress.split('\n')
   xs=[]
   ys=[]
   zs=[]
   for line in lines:
      if len(line)>1:
        x,y,z=line.split()
        x=float(x)
        y=float(y)
        z=float(z)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
        zs.append(z)
        point_stress.close()
   ax1.clear()
   ax1.plot(xs,ys,zs)
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Comment: it's not working anyway. I would like to add coordinate and at same time update the graph. With your script, is needed that all coordinate are already written.

Comment: How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


def init():
    global points
    points = np.loadtxt('Prova.txt')


def animate(i):
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(points[:i, 0], points[:i, 1], points[:i, 2])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=1000)
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

my txt file:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 4 0
0 1 0
0 6 1
1 0 2
10 1 0
0 0 1
1 3 0
0 1 0
4 0 1
```